# How to generate 64-bit Visual Studio projects from qmake

Tags: visual-studio, qt, qt-creator, qmake

I am using Qt Creator to create some shared library and application projects so that I can easily build them on Windows and Linux.  On Windows, some of us prefer using Visual Studio so I want to generate Visual Studio solution and project files from the Qt .pro files using **qmake -tp vc -r file.pro**.  Everything works exactly as expected except that the generated Visual Studio solution and projects only contain 32-bit build configurations and I need 64-bit configurations.  It's not a big deal to create the 64-bit configuration in Visual Studio but it would be an easy step to overlook for somebody.  I'm wondering if there's a way to do it automatically by either adding something to my .pro files or as an argument to qmake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run this command from the Visual Studio Command Shell Native x64.

If you need this functionality in any sort of batch files etc, just invoke appropriate bat file from VS Command Tools, like  vcvarsx86_amd64.bat or  vcvarsx86.bat to set a proper environment

Comment: That actually solves our problem before team members migrate to VS2015 with Qt extension.

Comment: That...should have been more obvious.  I'm running this from a batch script so it didn't even occur to me, but I just called **vcvarsx86_amd64.bat** in the same script to register the x64 environment variables and that did the trick.  Thanks!