# Converted a Qt project into a VC++ project - unresolved external symbols

Tags: c++, qt, linker-errors

Why cannot I build and run my project? I have added the required .lib files to the linker input properties, added the Qt "include" directory to additional input folders, copied the .dll files to the project folder etc. Visual Studio still complains about unresolved external symbols. What should I do?

The main.cpp file is like so:

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QLabel>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QLabel* label = new QLabel("Hello Qt!");
  label->show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

The .pro file looks like this:

```
######################################################################
# Automatically generated by qmake (3.1) Tue Jan 17 00:13:06 2017
######################################################################

QT += core gui widgets

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = hello
INCLUDEPATH += .

# Input
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

The error list is below:

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl QApplication::QApplication(int &,char * *,int)" (__imp_??0QApplication@@QEAA@AEAHPEAPEADH@Z) referenced in function main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __cdecl QApplication::~QApplication(void)" (__imp_??1QApplication@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static int __cdecl QApplication::exec(void)" (__imp_?exec@QApplication@@SAHXZ) referenced in function main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl QWidget::show(void)" (__imp_?show@QWidget@@QEAAXXZ) referenced in function main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl QLabel::QLabel(class QString const &,class QWidget *,class QFlags<enum Qt::WindowType>)" (__imp_??0QLabel@@QEAA@AEBVQString@@PEAVQWidget@@V?$QFlags@W4WindowType@Qt@@@@@Z) referenced in function main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __cdecl QLabel::~QLabel(void)" (__imp_??1QLabel@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void * __cdecl QLabel::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GQLabel@@UEAAPEAXI@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl QWidget::actionEvent(class QActionEvent *)" (?actionEvent@QWidget@@MEAAXPEAVQActionEvent@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl QLabel::changeEvent(class QEvent *)" (?changeEvent@QLabel@@MEAAXPEAVQEvent@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl QWidget::closeEvent(class QCloseEvent *)" (?closeEvent@QWidget@@MEAAXPEAVQCloseEvent@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl QLabel::contextMenuEvent(class QContextMenuEvent *)" (?contextMenuEvent@QLabel@@MEAAXPEAVQContextMenuEvent@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __cdecl QWidget::devType(void)const " (?devType@QWidget@@UEBAHXZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl QWidget::dragEnterEvent(class QDragEnterEvent *)" (?dragEnterEvent@QWidget@@MEAAXPEAVQDragEnterEvent@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl QWidget::dragLeaveEvent(class QDragLeaveEvent *)" (?dragLeaveEvent@QWidget@@MEAAXPEAVQDragLeaveEvent@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl QWidget::dragMoveEvent(class QDragMoveEvent *)" (?dragMoveEvent@QWidget@@MEAAXPEAVQDragMoveEvent@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl QWidget::dropEvent(class QDropEvent *)" (?dropEvent@QWidget@@MEAAXPEAVQDropEvent@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl QWidget::enterEvent(class QEvent *)" (?enterEvent@QWidget@@MEAAXPEAVQEvent@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual bool __cdecl QLabel::event(class QEvent *)" (?event@QLabel@@MEAA_NPEAVQEvent@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl QLabel::focusInEvent(class QFocusEvent *)" (?focusInEvent@QLabel@@MEAAXPEAVQFocusEvent@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual bool __cdecl QLabel::focusNextPrevChild(bool)" (?focusNextPrevChild@QLabel@@MEAA_N_N@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl QLabel::focusOutEvent(class QFocusEvent *)" (?focusOutEvent@QLabel@@MEAAXPEAVQFocusEvent@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __cdecl QWidget::hasHeightForWidth(void)const " (?hasHeightForWidth@QWidget@@UEBA_NXZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __cdecl QLabel::heightForWidth(int)const " (?heightForWidth@QLabel@@UEBAHH@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl QWidget::hideEvent(class QHideEvent *)" (?hideEvent@QWidget@@MEAAXPEAVQHideEvent@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl QWidget::initPainter(class QPainter *)const " (?initPainter@QWidget@@MEBAXPEAVQPainter@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl QWidget::inputMethodEvent(class QInputMethodEvent *)" (?inputMethodEvent@QWidget@@MEAAXPEAVQInputMethodEvent@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class QVariant __cdecl QWidget::inputMethodQuery(enum Qt::InputMethodQuery)const " (?inputMethodQuery@QWidget@@UEBA?AVQVariant@@W4InputMethodQuery@Qt@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl QLabel::keyPressEvent(class QKeyEvent *)" (?keyPressEvent@QLabel@@MEAAXPEAVQKeyEvent@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl QWidget::keyReleaseEvent(class QKeyEvent *)" (?keyReleaseEvent@QWidget@@MEAAXPEAVQKeyEvent@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl QWidget::leaveEvent(class QEvent *)" (?leaveEvent@QWidget@@MEAAXPEAVQEvent@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __cdecl QLabel::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@QLabel@@UEBAPEBUQMetaObject@@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual int __cdecl QWidget::metric(enum QPaintDevice::PaintDeviceMetric)const " (?metric@QWidget@@MEBAHW4PaintDeviceMetric@QPaintDevice@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class QSize __cdecl QLabel::minimumSizeHint(void)const " (?minimumSizeHint@QLabel@@UEBA?AVQSize@@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl QWidget::mouseDoubleClickEvent(class QMouseEvent *)" (?mouseDoubleClickEvent@QWidget@@MEAAXPEAVQMouseEvent@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl QLabel::mouseMoveEvent(class QMouseEvent *)" (?mouseMoveEvent@QLabel@@MEAAXPEAVQMouseEvent@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl QLabel::mousePressEvent(class QMouseEvent *)" (?mousePressEvent@QLabel@@MEAAXPEAVQMouseEvent@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl QLabel::mouseReleaseEvent(class QMouseEvent *)" (?mouseReleaseEvent@QLabel@@MEAAXPEAVQMouseEvent@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl QWidget::moveEvent(class QMoveEvent *)" (?moveEvent@QWidget@@MEAAXPEAVQMoveEvent@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual bool __cdecl QWidget::nativeEvent(class QByteArray const &,void *,long *)" (?nativeEvent@QWidget@@MEAA_NAEBVQByteArray@@PEAXPEAJ@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class QPaintEngine * __cdecl QWidget::paintEngine(void)const " (?paintEngine@QWidget@@UEBAPEAVQPaintEngine@@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl QLabel::paintEvent(class QPaintEvent *)" (?paintEvent@QLabel@@MEAAXPEAVQPaintEvent@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __cdecl QLabel::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QLabel@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __cdecl QLabel::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@QLabel@@UEAAPEAXPEBD@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual class QPaintDevice * __cdecl QWidget::redirected(class QPoint *)const " (?redirected@QWidget@@MEBAPEAVQPaintDevice@@PEAVQPoint@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl QWidget::resizeEvent(class QResizeEvent *)" (?resizeEvent@QWidget@@MEAAXPEAVQResizeEvent@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl QWidget::setVisible(bool)" (?setVisible@QWidget@@UEAAX_N@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual class QPainter * __cdecl QWidget::sharedPainter(void)const " (?sharedPainter@QWidget@@MEBAPEAVQPainter@@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl QWidget::showEvent(class QShowEvent *)" (?showEvent@QWidget@@MEAAXPEAVQShowEvent@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class QSize __cdecl QLabel::sizeHint(void)const " (?sizeHint@QLabel@@UEBA?AVQSize@@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl QWidget::tabletEvent(class QTabletEvent *)" (?tabletEvent@QWidget@@MEAAXPEAVQTabletEvent@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl QWidget::wheelEvent(class QWheelEvent *)" (?wheelEvent@QWidget@@MEAAXPEAVQWheelEvent@@@Z)
```

Comment: You need to link with a QT library; something that tells the linker the symbols that are in a DLL.

Comment: If there is no link to Qt then something went wrong with the project conversion which we don't know. I would try `qmake -tp vc -r file.pro` instead. There several ways to deal with Qt project -> VS project and you can try find some: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38248343/how-to-generate-64-bit-visual-studio-projects-from-qmake

Answer (score -1):

I had to convert the project once more into a VC++ project after I had edited the .pro file, I had not done that. The program works now.